# what does $batch$ mean? $ indicates of end of the string

Tags: asp.net, regex

(?i).*/api/data/.*/$batch$

what could be an example that matches this regex

http://crm.com/api/data and I don't know what that this $batch$ does?

I know $ is an anchor which indicates the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

This is just my best guess, but...

In the Unix shell, "$batch" would return the value of a variable named "batch", but "$" would return just a dollar sign since it has no variable name after it.

So it looks like they might first be inserting a variable called "batch" from the command line, and then the 2nd dollar sign would be output just as it is to form a regex expression. So if the variable batch equals "hello", it would output "hello$".